# Cannot Replay recorded Coded UI Test action for the button that is the part of the custom control

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I used VS 2010 Coded UI Test to record `Click` action to the `combobox` of Custom Control that consists  of `combobox` and button and generated a code.

Then I used VS 2010 Coded UI Test to record `Click` action to the button of Custom Control that consists  of `combobox` and button and generated code.

When I did Replay of the Click on the combobox it is working fine.

**When I did Replay of the Click on the button I got an exception:**

```
Cannot perform 'Click' on the hidden control
```

Coded UI Test after refresh can find and highlight the button.
It seems `UIMap.Designer` generates proper declaration of the Control.
Before performing "Click" on the Button I tried `SetFocus`.
If I get `ControlCollection` and show message with `BoundingRectangle` properties of every control in the collection then `BoundingRectangle` point to the different Control.

How to make recorded "Click" on the Button of the custom control to be re-playable.

Comment: Please stop using VS2010 it's really old now, upgrade to VS2013 (latest update) because you get much better record and playback with the new updates.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes controls are rendered as composites of other controls.
After the recorder finds your button, see if it has child controls (click on the Down arrow, or Alt + Down), [image: like here]. This happened to me several times while testing a Silverlight application, an image or text blocks the actual button.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I'm able to drill down to the child and then this child declaration is used in the generated code.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below solution once as the bounding rectangle is correct or not:-**

1. Do a ButtonControl.DrawHighlight(). Check if the entire correct button boundary is getting highlighted.
2. ButtonControl.BoundingRectangle. Does this return non-zero values ?
3. If [2] is true,
   Rectangle r = ButtonControl.BoundingRectangle.

ButtonControl.SetFocus()

Mouse.Click(new Point(r.X + r.Width/2, r.Y + r.Height/2));